# Contador Regresso

Tags: javascript

Tenho um contador porém gostaria de adaptá-lo a contar de maneira regressa, atualmente ele conta de 1 a 30, mas eu gostaria de maneira inversa... ou seja, do 30 ao 1.

```js
var time = 30;
var initialOffset = '149';
var i = 1

$('.circle_animation').css('stroke-dashoffset', initialOffset-(1*(initialOffset/time)));

var interval = setInterval(function() {
  $('h2').text(i);
  if (i == time) {   
   clearInterval(interval);
   return;
 }
 $('.circle_animation').css('stroke-dashoffset', initialOffset-((i+1)*(initialOffset/time)));
 i++;  
}, 1000);
```

```css
.item {
 position: relative;
 float: left;
}

.item h2 {
 text-align:center;
 position: absolute;
 line-height: 40px;
 width: 100%;
}

svg {
 transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.circle_animation {
  stroke-dasharray: 149;
  stroke-dashoffset: 149;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <h2>0</h2>
  <svg width="80" height="80" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle id="circle" class="circle_animation" r="23.85699" cy="40" cx="40" stroke-width="4" stroke="#000" fill="none"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível fazer isso criando uma nova variável de controle para a contagem, mantendo assim a variável `i` para a animação:

- Alteramos o valor do `h2` para 30.
- Criamos a variável `count` que será o contador regressivo.
- No `setInterval`, `count` vai ser decrementada: `count--`.
- Substituímos o `text` do `h2` pelo valor de `count`.
- E a verificação que limpa o `setInterval` passa a verificar se `count` é igual a 0.

```js
let time = 30;
let initialOffset = 149;
let i = 1;
let count = 29;

$('.circle_animation').css('stroke-dashoffset', initialOffset-(1*(initialOffset/time)));

let interval = setInterval(function() {
  $('h2').text(count);

  if (count == 0) {   
    clearInterval(interval);
    return;
  }

  $('.circle_animation').css('stroke-dashoffset', initialOffset-((i+1)*(initialOffset/time)));
  i++;
  count--;
}, 1000);
```

```css
.item {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.item h2 {
  text-align:center;
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
}

svg {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.circle_animation {
  stroke-dasharray: 149;
  stroke-dashoffset: 149;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <h2>30</h2>
  <svg width="80" height="80" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle id="circle" class="circle_animation" r="23.85699" cy="40" cx="40" stroke-width="4" stroke="#000" fill="none"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Em resumo, apenas invertemos a lógica presente na variável `i`.

---

Agora se você deseja que a animação também fique invertida, aí podemos trabalhar apenas com a variável `i`.

- Alteramos o valor do `h2` para 30.
- Alteramos a variável `i` para começar no próximo número do decremento.
- No setInterval, `i` passa a ser decrementada: `i--`.
- No `$('.circle_animation').css('stroke-dashoffset'...)` passamos a incrementar o valor, alterando os cálculos presentes.
- E a verificação que limpa o `setInterval` passa a verificar se `i` é igual a 0.

```js
let time = 30;
let initialOffset = 149;
let i = 29;

$('.circle_animation').css('stroke-dashoffset', 1);

let interval = setInterval(function() {
  $('h2').text(i);

  if (i == 0) {   
    clearInterval(interval);
    return;
  }

  $('.circle_animation').css('stroke-dashoffset', (time-i+1)*(initialOffset/time) );
  i--;  
}, 1000);
```

```css
.item {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.item h2 {
  text-align:center;
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
}

svg {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.circle_animation {
  stroke-dasharray: 149;
  stroke-dashoffset: 149;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <h2>30</h2>
  <svg width="80" height="80" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle id="circle" class="circle_animation" r="23.85699" cy="40" cx="40" stroke-width="4" stroke="#000" fill="none"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Entendi perfeitamente, obrigado pela ajuda.